# Get datastore entity's parent key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get the parent key from a certain entity.
I have 2 classes, Album and Photo. Album is a parent to photo, so when I upload a photo I assign the key of that certain album it belongs to as a parent to the photo.

```
album = db.get(self.album_key)
photo = Photo(parent=album)
```

Problem arises when I try to query for the parent id from photo. The below code just gives me an output of "parent key: <"

```
photo = db.get(photo_key)
photoparent =  photo.parent

self.response.out.write("parent key: %s" %photoparent)
```

How can I properly pull the parent key from a Photo instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parent is a method call, not a property.

So you code should read

> photoparent =  photo.parent()

See docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_parent

Also when the key is output in

> self.response.out.write("parent key: %s" %photoparent)

The keys **str** method outputs a representation of the object with <>'s  So you may want to do something with the parent to make it's html output more sane ;-)

Cheers

Tim

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was able to get the parent key through "photo.parent().key()"   I wasn't able to use photo.parent_key() though, didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Freddy I'm having the same issue. Is it correct to assume that you can't get the parent using the children key ?(i.e. the album from the photo)

Comment: You can get the parent from the child if the key was created with a parent. Also look at the differing api's db vs ndb as the specifics on how you do this.